# Can I publish a podcast at Apple for only one country

Tags: podcasts

The subject says it all: Can I publish a podcast at Apple for only one country? Where can I find documents regarding this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've searched several sources: it looks like Podcasts are always international.